# xamarin Forms Azure Notification Hubs

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

everyone,
i have developed an app with Xamarin Forms and i want to implement Push Notification.
I use Azure Notificatio hubs to implement push notification.
I can now receive the push notification in my app but I want to group the push notification (send push notification to determine device)
I want the user to select certain category to receive notification.
but the documentation from Microsoft, does not explain how to do this. the documentation said how to implement push notification with Java, Swift (Native App).
but i want to do everything with C#, because i use Xamarin forms.
can someone please help me???

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Routing and Tag Expressions**, Which enable you to target specific sets of devices, or more specifically registrations, when sending a push notification through Notification Hubs.

Tags can be used to subscribe to message categories such as news, sports, and weather. For simplicity, the sample application defines a default template with a single parameter called messageParam and a single tag called default. In more complex systems, user-specific tags can be used to message a user across devices for personalized notifications. To learn more about tags, see **[Routing and tag expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-tags-segment-push-message)**.

For more details you could refer the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/azure-services/azure-notification-hub#register-templates-and-tags-with-the-azure-notification-hub) .

Comment: thanks for your answer.
but that wasn't my question.
i understand exactly what you mean, and i want to do the same.
but i want to know how i can subscribe to a category with xamarin forms
in the documentation there are examples only with java and swift

Comment: yes i have read the doc. but i want users to subscribe to a group and not insert the group statically